# How to build a JAR file using ant for uiautomator test project

Tags: android, ant, ui-automation, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I have been trying to get my head around using uiautomator and I understand creating the test cases. I tried the first two steps of building the JAR according the the Android developer guide for UI Testing (http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html) and that worked fine, but I am unsure on how to follow the next steps and building the JAR file with ant. Please can anyone help me with this issue.

Here are the steps that I have done so far:

```
<android-sdk>/tools/android create uitest-project -n <name> -t 1 -p <path>

set ANDROID_HOME=<path_to_your_sdk>
```

This is the step that I am stuck on:

```
ant build
```

The error I get when I use the command prompt is:

```
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal run

```
which ant
```

It seems you do not have ant installed. If no location like /usr/bin/ant shows up after you run the command above, use this to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ant
```

Try again after. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ADT, I recommend downloading Apache ant and placing it within the sdk/tools/ant folder. Then change your PATH variable to direct to the ant bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

you have this error because you wrote "ant build" from incorrect path.

I did (this command generate build.xml, local.properties, project.properties files):

```
<android-sdk>/tools/android create uitest-project -n <name> -t 1 -p <path>
```

I changed in build.xml first line like:

```
<project name="name" default="build">
```

after that I run ant from eclipse. Build was success.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed ant? If not then do it from this site: http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html

If yes then follow these steps:

1. Navigate to your project directory and means (go to bin of your project)
2. Using command window execute the function: ant build

Ensure that your default JAVA_HOME points to JDK installation, not the JRE, and check if your compiler is in the PATH. Try to type “javac” in the command prompt. If javac is not found, then you should put your bin directory in the PATH.
For example, in Windows:

```
SET PATH=c:/jdk1.5.0_07/bin;%PATH%
```

This site might help further: http://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/02/08/uiautomator-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

If you have ADT with Eclipse then you can find ant in the plugins directory of Eclipse.